# Overriding/hiding Javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to do something like this in Javascript:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    return true;
};

var anotherFunction = function () {
    return false;
};

$(function () {
    this.myFunction = anotherFunction;

    myFunction(); // to return false
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExfP6/)

My intuition says yes, but it doesn't work. How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: One of those - it's getting late in the day stupidity things. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does work, you have just made a typo (missed off the `this`) that is causing the old function to be called;

```
$(function () {
    this.myFunction = anotherFunction;

    this.myFunction(); // to return false
});
```

or

```
$(function () {
    myFunction = anotherFunction;

    myFunction(); // to return false
});
```

In the context where you are overiding, `this.myFunction` and `myFunction` refer to different things.

Here is your fixed fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ExfP6/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can override any variable inside the outer scope with another variable with the same name:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    return true;
};

var anotherFunction = function () {
    return false;
};

$(function () {
    var myFunction = anotherFunction; // override the myFunction name inside this scope

    myFunction(); // returns false
});

myFunction(); // returns true
```

You can read more about scope here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Comment: var myFunction = anotherFunction; // is it overriding or using new variable ?

Comment: @SHIN It is using a new variable that hides the one in the outer scope. As you can see in the outer scope myFunction() still returns true. Well i suppose you can argue that the code inside $() is executed after the call to myFunction() on the last line, but even if it was executed before, the myFunction in the outer scope would still be unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExfP6/2/)

```
var myFunction = function () {
    return true;
};

var anotherFunction = function () {
    return false;
};

$(function () {
    myFunction = anotherFunction; //remove this. your function was attach to a variable so by reassigning that variable with "anotherFunction" you will get the desired result.

    $('#result').html(""+myFunction());
});
```